# How to Run Postgresql procedures with Knex in Node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I am trying to call a stored procedure saved in the public schema using:

```
const schema = await knex.raw("call create_schema(?, 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6')",
        schema_name);
```

The procedure is to create a schema for a new tenant in the database.

However, I keep getting this error:

```
"call create_schema($1, 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6') - procedure create_schema(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist"
```

Please what could be the problem and how I can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, I needed to use `knex.schema.raw()`. Also, I used the wrong database name that didn't have the procedure in it.